# LAN9500A Linux USB Ethernet Driver Problem!

Tags: linux, drivers, ethernet, arm, usb-device

I'm working on a custom board equipped with a iMX28 module and the LAN9500A USB to Ethernet controller without EEPROM for the network interface. Operating system is Linux (kernel v3.16). The LAN9500A is connected to a RJ45 jack with integrated Magnetics and LEDs.

I check the reference schematics of Microchip against my design. 
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9500a_sch.pdf

I can see the LAN9500A is detected and correct driver is loaded...,

```
# dmesg | grep -i smsc
[    1.549126] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    2.186356] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    2.258622] smsc95xx 1-1:1.0 eth2: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-ci_hdrc.1-1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, 62:94:6a:f1:ec:26
[    9.588663] fec 800f0000.ethernet eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720] (mii_bus:phy_addr=800f0000.etherne:00, irq=-1)
```

After the system is turned on, the link and activity LEDs are lit ...

```
# ifconfig eth2 up
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
root@imx28evk:~# IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
smsc95xx 1-1:1.0 eth2: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1
IPv6: eth2: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::fa:25ff:fe59:cf38 detected!

# ifconfig eth2 down
```

LEDs are still on ...

```
# ifconfig eth2 up
smsc95xx 1-1:1.0 eth2: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1

# ifconfig eth2 down
```

LEDs are still on ...

```
$ ifconfig eth2 up
```

Now the LEDs are off ...

```
# ethtool eth2
Settings for eth2:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 10Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no

# mii-tool eth2
eth2: no link

# ifconfig eth2 down 

$ ifconfig eth2 up
smsc95xx 1-1:1.0 eth2: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
```

LEDs light up

```
ethtool eth2
Settings for eth2:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes

# mii-tool eth2
eth2: negotiated 1000baseT-HD flow-control, link ok
```

Another issue is that when I unplug and plug the Ethernet cable from the RJ45 socket, Linux does not detect it, ...

Has anyone else seen this? 
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Your kernel is very old, 3.16 wasn't today. We are now around at 4.12 . I suggest to refresh your kernel.

Comment: I tested 4.4 and 4.9... The problem still occurs.

Comment: I couldn't compile kernel 4.12 for imx28...

Comment: Then it looks as a driver problem. If it is, then - unless you aren't a hardcore kernel hacker, with windows driver reverse engineering skills - you have no chance. A possible workaround would be 1) using [ndiswrapper](https://wiki.debian.org/NdisWrapper) OR 2) to install a minimal-configuration winxp in a virtual machine, giving it direct access to the usb device. However, if I understand you well, you are on an embedded, non-x86 architecture, it makes the things far more hard (although still not impossible).

Comment: You could also run a virtual x86 linux in a qemu, and using ndiswrapper on it.

Comment: I am on an embedded Linux system );

Comment: You can still start a virtual x86 bootdisk in a qemu with an ndiswrapper on it. It won't be very fast, it won't be very stable (but you can write automatic reset/reconnect scripts), it is a lot of work to make, but it would work. What architecture does it have, arm? How many ram do you have? What is your cpu frequency?

Comment: Read driver code, read LAN9500A datasheet, start to debug the driver. Or at least file a bug on https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: Help me! Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this problem has been somewhat solved in **Linux Kernel 3.16.48**.